# NLOG & Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, logging, nlog, azure-table-storage

everything is logging just fine except for the fact that its recording 2 columns that I believe is causing ***Azure Storage Explorer*** to freak out when sorting via the application. See image below.

[image]

Can anyone explain what the difference between Timestamp and LogTimeStamp is here?

When there are a ton of entries the sorting here gets horribly complicated where I am missing log entries.

See example of my current config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- include this assembly as an NLog extension -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- set up a an azure storage table target -->
  <targets>
    <target name="AzureTableStorage"
        xsi:type="AzureTableStorage"
        PartitionKey="${date}.${logger}"
        RowKey="${guid}"
        ConnectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
        tableName="Bootloader" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- set up a rule to log to the azure storage target! -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="AzureTableStorage" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp Time zone is UTC.

LogTimeStamp Time zone is Local.